# How to Store Non English Words In Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, insert, tamil

```
Insert into Tamil_language values (1, N'மோதிரம்')
Insert into Tamil_language values (2, 'மோதிரம்')

Select * from Tamil_language
```

Output

```
i      j
----------- ----------
1      மோதிரம்
2      ???????
```

How to do this using store procedure in Oracle Database?
How To Add 'N' Prefix For the Store procedure Parameter?
Please Help me if any one know this.

Comment: Which tool do you use? What is the database character set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am Using Pl/SQL Developer 13 and Oracle Database 12c .

Comment: Insert into Tamil_language values (1, 'பெண்டிரேம்')
Insert into Tamil_language values (1, N'பெண்டிரேம்')

Select * from Tamil_language
Output
i      j
----------- ----------
1      ??????????
1      பெண்டிரேம்

Comment: How to add N Prefix for Store Procedure Parameter ?